# SQL Server: correct escaping Where clause in dynamic procedure (2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, escaping

I have a dynamic procedure where I want to use the below as part of my Where clause (everything else works as intended).

Currently this creates the following error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'`

```
AND         CASE WHEN ' + @searchCategory + ' <> ''dateRec'' THEN
                (R.' + @searchCategory + ' LIKE ''%' + @searchTerm + '%'')
                ELSE
                (R.dateRec = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @searchTerm, 111) + ')
                END
```

What would the proper escaping look like here ?

Comment: Post the whole query please, you've removed quotes, and the dynamic sql is inverted with non-dynamic.

Comment: The rest of the procedure works and is too long to be posted here - it is only about these lines.

Comment: OK, that's fine, this is invalid `CASE WHEN xxx <> 'dateRec' THEN (R.xxx LIKE '%yyy%')` the THEN statement tells SQL what to use, and you're doing another comparison.  This is not a ' issue, its a syntax issue.

Comment: Ok, that's possible. I dont have much experience with dynamic procedures. How would I write it correctly ?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I have an input variable (@searchTerm) that can be either a date (if @searchCategory = dateRec) or a string but the variable is defined as nvarchar so I am trying to find a way to cover both cases. For the date I need to search in a datetime column and for the rest in nvarchar columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @searchCategory nvarchar(max), @searchTerm nvarchar(max)
set @searchCategory = 'dateRec'
set @searchTerm = 'yyy'

set @sql = 
'AND (
       (''' + @searchCategory + ''' <> ''dateRec'' AND (R.' + @searchCategory + ' LIKE ''%' + @searchTerm + '%''))
       OR
       (''' + @searchCategory + ''' = ''dateRec'' AND (R.dateRec = ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @searchTerm, 111) + '''))
     )'
print @sql
```

Comment: This is great - thanks a lot ! What does the print do in the end ? I am currently ending my procedure with EXEC(@sql).

Comment: This embeds the free form text of `@searchTerm` in to the SQL.  This opens you up to a LittleBobbyTables SQL Injection Attack.  Instead of using `EXEC` this shoudl use `sp_executesql` and so still be able to pass parameters to the dynamic-sql.  This way only the `@searchCategory` needs substituting in to the sql-string, and that can be white-list checked to ensure it's not an attack.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the contents of @searchCategory don't actaully contain the characters `'`...

```
SET @sql = 'AND ' +
           CASE WHEN @searchCategory <> 'dateRec' THEN
             '(R.' + @searchCategory + ' LIKE ''%'' + @searchTerm + ''%'')'
           ELSE
             '(R.dateRec = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @searchTerm, 111))'
           END
```

This will give either....

```
AND (R.foobar LIKE '%' + @searchTerm + '%')
```

or...

```
AND (R.dateRec = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @searchTerm, 111))
```

This means that you would still pass `@searchTerm` to `sp_executesql` as a parameter, so as to protect you from SQL Injection attacks.

You DO NOT want to directly embed a user's free form text in to your SQL.  Free form text *must* stay as a parameter in order to close that security hole.

*(I'm also assuming that you have a white-list of valid values of `@searchCategory` so as to prevent that from being abused with an SQL Injection Attack?.)*

**EDIT :**

An example of dynamic sql that maintains parameterisation....

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(500);

SET @SQLString = N'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ' + @param1 + ' = @param;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql
   @SQL,
   '@param NVARCHAR(500)',
   @param2
```

Using this method, you need to check that @param1 really is a legitimate field name, using a white-list for example, but you do not need to check @param2.  This is because @param2 is being passed to `sp_executesql` as a parameter itself.  It's just like dynamically making a stored procedure with parameters, rather than embedding all your values in the sql string, which lays you open to serious sql injection attacks.

**EDIT :**

This is ***not*** a case of embedding a `LIKE` statement within a `CASE` statement.  What is being done here is creating a string that creates the string literal `LIKE`, by using a CASE statement.

It is much the same as this...

```
SET @sql = 'AND ' +
           CASE WHEN @searchCategory <> 'dateRec' THEN
             'A string with the word' + ' LIKE ' + 'in it'
           ELSE
             'A different string without that word in it'
           END
```

Comment: @JiggsJedi - It doesn't do what you think.  the `LIKE` is just a piece of text (a string literal), not a command.   It's a case statement builds up a SQL String, where the SQL String contains the text `LIKE`.  It is not a case statement with a LIKE statement inside it.

Comment: @JiggsJedi - I'm not saying that is valid at all.  You are right that your example is valid.  What I have written is not what is in your example.  I'll update my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: I retract my comments.  I swear to you, the CASE was in the '' when I first looked.  You are correct sir.